# User Acceptance Citeria and Job Descriptions

Tags: jenkins, gradle, ansible, devops

As  a Technical Recruiter I am often put into the category of oh No not another one. It is my goal to break that stigma. How can do that when I get the following as a job description:

JavaScript, Unix, Ansible, Dev Ops, Gradle, Git, Jenkins, Bit Bucket. As a member of the Middleware Integration team, you will be responsible for Building, configuring, and deploying the middleware applications to the development and QA environments. Tools such as Ansible, Git, Gradle, Jenkins, and Bit Bucket are used to build, maintain, and deploy the applications. In addition, you will also need to perform basic application, environment, and server troubleshooting.

Question 1: I can tell manager is looking for DevOps Developer however, I don't have anything else to satisfy User Acceptance Criteria. Does this really help candidates in their search when you see requirements like so?

Question 2: Do you think that HR needs a change in the way talent managment is handled?

I've been testing agile practices and concepts learned from my individual development and need  certifications acquired. Im in my 2nd iteration and seeing improvements already.

Go easy on me.....this is my first post! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This job description sounds reasonable, but it lacks some key details to understand how high is the bar.

Does company already have a some workflow? Can you give a coarse description of it? (example git push -> jenkins (manual) -> jdg -> deb -> aptly -> jeknins + ansible for update(manual)). Is company want to maintain and continue it, or is it want to remake it from scratch? Or, may be, it has none, and want some hero to create one?

What level of autonomy would-be devops would have? Can it throw away bitbucket and replace it with gitlab or not? Is ansible must or there is a place for chef/puppet? Is gradle means some nasty java is there? Can operator choose distro?

How large is operator team in the company? Working with a team is a completely different level of operations compare to 'company of programmers finally need at least someone to do ops job'.

I'm not in a job search process, but if I would, those questions would be important for me.